# Reading applink query parameters in cached Instant App

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, android-instant-apps, android-app-links

After Instant App is being loaded to cache it stops to store intent data

I am trying to provide different query params to launch my Instant App storing on GooglePlay.

First launch is good, i can see full link in intentData, but on second launch after app is cached intentData returns null instead of launch link

(link should look like - "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iamdev.myinstantapp&launch=true&location=home&lnk=W8vbGFuZG1hcmtzLWRlbW8v"

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am unable to see the full link in intent data even for the first launch

Comment: Unfortunately no, after publishing app to Google Play query parameters available only once until app cache is cleared